# DELPHI XE5 and dbxjson - tojson

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe5

I need to create a program that runs on win `XP` (old server) and therefore it must be programmed in Delphi `XE5`.

The program must post a json to a website (with indy), and it is working like a dream under `XE7`, but I cannot get it to run under `XE5` due to national characters in the json values, I think.

I create the json in the object `TJSONObject` and under `XE7` I retrieve the escaped json with the function obj.tojson and post this wi indy http.

The .tojson function does not exist under `XE5`. Does anyone know how to retrieve the same in `XE5` (equvalent to .tojson, not .tostring) and return this as a string?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question. In Delphi XE5 the decoded value is extracted from the JSON by

```
data :=obj.Get('access_token').JsonValue.Value
```

While in Delphi XE7 this is done by

```
data :=obj.GetValue('access_token').ToString;
```